# How to make reports in visual studio 2013 report viewer from a dynamic dataset?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to make report in visual studio 2013 report viewer using a dataset that I have created in my code. I am new so its unclear on how to do it.I have tried this after following tutorials. I make a data table in the dataset.xsd with the same schema as my data table in the code.It gives me the columns of the data set and I add them into my report.

But when I add my report in the report viewer and run it,it gives the following error

> Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSet'. The Select
>   operation is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource3'
>   unless the SelectMethod is specified.

ObjectDatasource3 is I guess the connection,it asks me to choose a my business object and when I select the available option from the drop down it says cannot find that object.

Comment: Did you deploy BOTH the report and the datasource to the report server?   Deploying the report doesn't automatically deploy the data source.

Comment: yes well i think i did because ObjectDataSource is my data source   How is it done How can I know for sure if I did it right?

Comment: On your report server, right-click your report, and choose "Manage", then on the left-side bar, choose "Data Sources".   Post what you see there.

Comment: I am using report viewer if that s different from report server that u mentioned. All right managing data source led me to a drop down with a value myproject.TableAdapter and when I select it, it says could not find

Comment: Well that's definitely the problem, but your screen is different from mine, so I guess report viewer is different.  I've never used it.   So I don't know how to diagnose further.   Good luck.